# Prove the equality of this complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

How I prove that if $a,b,z\in\mathbb{C}$, $\rho\in\mathbb{R}$ then

$$ \left | z\right |^2+\frac{\left | a\right |^2-\rho^2\left | b\right |^2}{1-\rho^2}-2Re\left ( z\frac{\overline{\left | a\right |^2-\rho ^2 \left | b\right |^2}}{1-\rho^2}\right )=\left | z-\frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2}\right |^2-\left | \frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2}\right |+\frac{\left | a\right |^2-\rho^2\left | b\right |^2}{1-\rho^2}$$

I have tried all I know, first I prove this use that $2Re\left( x\right)=x+\overline{x}$, and nothing, second I use that is that equation is true then

$$ \left | z\right |^2-2Re\left ( z\frac{\overline{\left | a\right |^2-\rho ^2 \left | b\right |^2}}{1-\rho^2}\right )=\left | z-\frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2}\right |^2-\left | \frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2}\right |$$

but I don't get something reasonable to apply that in my way to prove the equality, help please

Comment: One observation is that there is a common term on both sides of the equation.
Where does this come from? Are you sure that $a-\rho^2b\,$ should not be $a-\rho b$?

Answer (score 0):

$$\left | z-\frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2}\right |^2 = ( z-\frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2}) \overline {( z-\frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2})} \\= z\bar z-(z\overline {\frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2}})-(\bar z\frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2})+(\frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2})\overline {(\frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2})}\\ =|z|^2 + |\frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2}|^2-(z\overline {\frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2}})-(\bar z\frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2})$$

Note that $$ \overline{(\bar z\frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2})} = z\overline {\frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2}} $$

We get 
$$(\bar z\frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2})+z\overline {\frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2}}=2Re(z\overline {\frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2}})$$

Therefore, original equation becomes

$$ |z|^2 + |\frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2}|^2 - 2Re(z\overline {\frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2}}) = |z-\frac{a-\rho^2b}{1-\rho^2}|^2$$

Comment: Use formula $|a-b|^2 = |a|^2-2Re(a\bar b)+|b|^2$ is immediate